Are global symmetries vectors in configuration space?
The generic definition of a symmetry in terms of an action is simply some transformation leaving the action invariant. If we have some configuration space $\mathrm{Conf}$, for instance for a point particle
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Conf} = C^\infty(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^n)
\end{equation}
and the action is some functional
\begin{equation}
S : \mathrm{Conf} \to \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}
Then a symmetry is just some automorphism on $\mathrm{Conf}$ leaving the action invariant :
\begin{equation}
f \in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Conf}),\ S \circ f= S.
\end{equation}
If we have our action $S$, the set of physical configurations is the critical locus of the $1$-form $\delta S$, ie the set on which this $1$-form vanishes :
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Crit}(S) = \{ \phi \in \mathrm{Conf} | \delta S_\phi = 0 \}.
\end{equation}
A specific case of symmetries we can consider is the type generated by some vector on $T \mathrm{Conf}$. If we pick a configuration $\phi \in \mathrm{Conf}$, and a one-parameter group $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Conf})$, such that every element is a symmetry of $S$, this generates a flow of $\phi$ along a curve, giving a family of configurations
\begin{equation}
\gamma(0) = \phi,\ \gamma(t) = \phi_t
\end{equation}
such that $S(\phi_t)$ is a constant for all values of $t$. This gives rise to a vector $v = \dot{\gamma}(0)$, for which we have
\begin{equation}
\delta S[v] = v[S] = 0
\end{equation}
ie the derivative in the $v$ direction is zero, since the action is constant along it.
By the Morse lemma, we have that any critical point $\phi \in \mathrm{Crit}(S)$ is isolated if the Hessian of $S$ is non-degenerate, $\det \delta^2 S \neq 0$ (those corresponding to actions without gauge symmetries), in the sense that there is a neighbourhood $U \subset \mathrm{Conf}$ for which $\phi \in U$ and there are no other critical points in $U$, meaning that for a non-gauge theory, the shell in the configuration space is totally disconnected.
Does that mean that any non-gauge symmetry, including "parametrized" ones like translation etc are discontinuous in the configuration space? For instance if we take some time translation symmetry
\begin{eqnarray}
T : \mathrm{Conf} \times \mathbb{R} &\to& \mathrm{Conf}\\
(\phi, a) &\mapsto& \phi(- + a)
\end{eqnarray}
which, on an object in the shell, will map to other objects in the shell, as the new derivative also vanishes
\begin{equation}
\delta_{\phi(- + a)} S = \delta_{\phi} S = 0.
\end{equation}
Is the action of this symmetry entirely discontinuous in $\mathrm{Conf}$?

As you are dealing with spaces of functions: what topology are you using? Does Morse lemma is still valid for weak topologies? In Lagrangian mechanics there are apparently easy  counter examples: rotating a solution of EL equations of a rotational invariant Lagrangian produces another solution for every value of the rotation angle…

I would assume the Hessian has zero eigenvalues whenever the equation of motion is well posed.


Let us assume that the Lagrangian depends on time derivatives, so that we have a dynamical (rather than a static) physical system. Then we need to impose boundary conditions (BCs) to have a well-posed variational problem.

Critical points are determined by the Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations plus the BCs. In point mechanical applications, there are typically only a discrete number of critical points/instanton sectors.

Note that a symmetry transformation (ST) does typically not map a critical point into a critical point as a ST does typically not preserve BCs, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post.

Example: A free particle $L=\frac{m}{2}\dot{q}^2$ with Dirichlet BCs $$ q(t_i)~=~q_i\quad\text{and}\quad q(t_f)~=~q_f;$$ and translational symmetry $q\to q+a.$



+1 Yes, symmetries send solutions of EL equations to solutions of the same equations. However, they generally do not send critical points to critical points just because they change the functional: its domain. At first glance, it seems that this fact shows a limitation of the approach, in classical mechanics at least, since this type of  obstruction seems quite artificial. A symmetry should be, first of all, a map that sends solutions to solutions. There is no reason why it should also preserve boundary conditions. Also because the problem with BCs is not well posed in classical mechanics.

Well, it is not a limitation, but it has to be properly handled. Indeed at the level of the action  functional, a symmetry generally  changes the functional but not the value of it. The term $\delta^\mu_\nu {\cal L}$ in the canonical stress energy  tensor arises for that reason.
